# Proper way to deal with options in a pop up window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have some items in a list which decrease a internal value, when this value is 0, a windows pops and ask for what to do, there are 3 options, set the item as 'completed', set the item as 'missed', set the item as 'delayed'.

The window is a QDockWidget and options are selected via QPushButtons, I want to connect them to a function that will deal with each of the 3 actions possible.

like

```
self.options_button_completed.clicked.connect(self.set_completed)
self.options_button_missed.clicked.connect(self.set_missed)
self.options_button_delayed.clicked.connect(self.set_delayed)
```

But I can't do this way because I need the reference to the item that raised the window in the first place

I wonder if it's possible to set the clicked slot in a way that it will also pass a extra argument, the item who raised the QDockWidget.

Is it possible? Or else, what's the proper way to deal with this?

I assume that I would need to keep a variable with the item, but I'm looking for a more clean way, without clogging the class with variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making the Window a separated QWidget I'm able to instantiate it in the main window and pass and extra argument(item) which will be a instance attribute.

```
class MainFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.popup_windows = [] # to store the pops

def display_popup_window(self, item):
    # item is the reference item that it's internal value reached 0
    popup_window = PopupFrame(self, item)
    popup_window.show()
    popup_window._raise()
    self.popup_windows.append(popup_window)


class PopupFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, item):
        self.parent = parent
        self.item = item
        # set up other things, like buttons, layout...
        self.options_button_completed.clicked.connect(self.set_completed)
        self.options_button_missed.clicked.connect(self.set_missed)
        self.options_button_delayed.clicked.connect(self.set_delayed)

    def set_completed(self):
        # do something with self.item
        pass
```

It's simplified just to convey the general idea, if anyone need a working example, feel free to ask in the comments and I'll provided.